# Running MVC6 Beta8 app on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-mvc

I just updated to MVC6 Beta8. After a few hours fixing the code to compile again, I run into an issues that the app does not run under IIS Express. I'm getting this error message:

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.EntryPoint' from assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.EntryPoint' from assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9922864
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261

I know there were changes to the hosting architecture. But does this mean that we can't use IIS express anymore or it's just a matter of update or configuration change?

Comment: Did you even google it? [one](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2790) [two](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2834) & [original source](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/70) Need new webtoolextensions/dnvm (links are on that issue). As an aside, you should, if you're not already, be following github.com/aspnet/announcements. Also, you should be running with `dnx kestrel` now.

Comment: @BradChristie, Yes, I found both of the posts and the announcement as well. They state the problem, but not the solution (at east I don't see it there, maybe missing something obvious). How to run dnx kestel for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few breaking changes to the IIS/IIS Express hosting model that you need to account for when upgrading to beta8.

In your project.json file, remove these from dependencies:

- "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener"

Add the following to your dependencies:

- "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler

Finally, in your Startup.cs file, add the following to the Configure method:

- `app.UseIISPlatformHandler();`

(I'm assuming `app` is the name of your IApplicationBuilder, you can adjust accordingly).

This will add the new IISPlatformHandler to the pipeline and directs traffic to the Kestrel server, therefore bypassing IIS and the old Helios dnx host.

You can read up on this change in the announcements on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)

Comment: Did that and still got the same issue. What can you say about your "commands" section on project.json? Thx

Comment: I had to switch my web command from "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini" to "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel" then this answer worked.

Comment: If this still doesn't work. check the `web.config` file in wwwroot. The `system.webServer` section should only contain the `httpPlatformHandler` handler an its configuration. Other handlers will prevent IISExpress from starting.
You can create a new blank project to see the vanilla `web.config` file.

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove the web.config file from your project entirely. A 'vanilla' web.config will be generated at compile time that contains only the necessary handler to route requests to Kestrel.

Comment: don't forget about `dnu restore`

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I resolved the problem:

1. Download and install latest WebToolsExtentions from
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442
2. Create a new ASP.NET5 Web Application project
3. Copy your files from an old project to a new project

I could not figure out how to modify the existing project.

Comment: Right. Just copying files will not work - there are many breaking changes in Beta 8, and not all of them are properly documented. For example, new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath) from a previous template would not work anymore and you have to use SetBasePath() instead. Or navigation properties work differently when there's a foreign key property (had to add [ForeignKey] declaration.

Comment: struggled for days after upgrading my version through console. this answer fixed it instantly. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to beta 8 and solved it by removing the following dependencies from `project.json`:

`"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7"`
`"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7"`

And adding the following dependency:

`"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8"`

I also updated all the project references from `beta7`to `beta8`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way. Someone can find something usefull. I added this lines to my project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
```

And I changed commands from:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
},
```

to this:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
},
```

then `dnu restore`

Now you can run your asp.net application with `dnx web` or `dnx kestrel` command. Differences are described here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Servers