# ASP .NET 5 Empty Project returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-core

I've created a new Web Application, using the empty ASP .NET 5 preview template. The project builds after I run `dnu restore`.

When I run it, I get an empty response (i.e. blank page). Refreshing the page, I get a "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error" typical page with no useful info (see screenshot below).

[image]

I'm using the standard boilerplate code from the project template:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I set a breakpoint, it tells me the breakpoint won't be hit.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get this simplest of scenarios working?

**Edit**: project.json is the default one that comes with the project template (uses beta 5, which I know is not the latest):

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the project.json file? Also, tell us what version of dnx are you using

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Command Prompt? Which runtime are you using (eg. `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-final`)? Can you provide your `project.json` dependencies?

Comment: Edited the question. Running from VS2015 (sorry, thought that was clear). Selected runtime seems to be 1.0.0-rc1-update1. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: No, sorry. Problem persists after switching to 1.0.0-beta5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just crazy what I had to go through to make this work. Summary:

- Go to `%userprofile%`, delete everything in .dnx\packages (just to make sure there aren't conflicts between different beta runtime versions)
- Make sure latest runtime is being used
- `dnu restore`
- Replace dependencies in project.json as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186978/983064)
- As per comment below that answer, replace `"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"` with `"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"`
- In Startup.cs, replace `using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;` with `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`
- Run project with command line invoking `dnx web`, NOT from Visual Studio

Moral of the story: the "preview template" that comes with Visual Studio is WAY out of date, and you're better off starting a fresh project.

Note: at the time of writing, the latest runtime is `1.0.0-rc1-update1`.